# Complex SQL with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables created in mysql.  I am having difficulty creating a query that will give me the list of organizations with the sum of funds that have been raised by them.  The funds will come from STUDENT AmountRaised and DONORS AmountContributed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
StudentFirstName char(100) NOT NULL,
StudentLastName char(100) NOT NULL,
OrgID INT NOT NULL
AmountRaised INT NOT NULL,
Captain Char(3) Null,
);

CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATIONS(
OrgID INT PRIMARY KEY,
OrgName char(100) Not Null,
OrgCategory char(100) Not NULL,
AmountRaised int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE KIDS (
KidId int PRIMARY KEY,
KidFirstName char(100) NOT NULL,
KidLastName char(100) NOT NULL,
OrgID INT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE DONORS(
DonorID int Primary Key,
DonorFirstName char(100) NOT NULL,
DonorLastName char(100) NOT NULL,
DonorOrganization char(100) NOT NULL,
AmountContributed int NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: edit the question with some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: Also please tell us how these tables are related to one another.  Without knowing that, a join query can't really be written.

Comment: There's syntax errors here

Comment: Unless all students have names comprising exactly 100 characters, Char(100) is extremely wasteful. See varchar

Comment: So how far have you got with your own query? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Organizations has amountraised column so why do you care about the other tables?

Comment: Maybe this question should be at database forum in StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it would be something like:

```
SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM (
    (
        SELECT o.id as id, sum(d.AmountContributed) as amount
        FROM organizations o
        JOIN donors d ON d.donororganization = o.id
        GROUP BY o.id
    ) AS t
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT o.id as id, sum(s.AmountRaised) as amount
        FROM organizations o
        JOIN student s ON s.orgid = o.id
        GROUP BY o.id
    ) AS t
) as t
GROUP BY o.id;
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis and every derived table myst have its own alias.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do:

```
select orgid, sum(AmountRaised) as AmountRaised, sum(AmountDonated) as AmountDonated,
       (sum(AmountRaised) + sum(AmountDonated)) as total
from ((select s.orgid, AmountRaised, 0 as AmountDonated
       from student s
      ) union all
      (select d.orgid, 0 as AmountRaised, AmountDonated
       from donors d
      )
     ) o
group by orgid;
```

You can use an additional `join` to bring in additional data about organizations.